Error starting Java Struts 6 app in Tomcat
I am having an issue deploying my application with Apache Tomcat 9 and Java 14, the application runs fine with Jetty server but I am having an issue when deploying it on Tomcat.
Here is the error I get
 org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [manageApp]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1751)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:453)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:407)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/enadmintool]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
            ... 42 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> [login] in servlet mapping
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3032)
            at org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:917)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1500)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1287)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:961)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4820)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
            ... 43 more
    23-Dec-2024 08:50:55.370 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [createStandardContext]
        javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method [manageApp]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:304)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:453)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:407)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
            at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
            at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
            at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1751)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
            ... 34 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/enadmintool]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
            ... 42 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> [login] in servlet mapping
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3032)
            at org.apache.catalina.Context.addServletMappingDecoded(Context.java:917)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1500)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1287)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:961)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:290)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4820)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
            ... 43 more

Seems the error is with the LoginAction class, here is my LoginAction Class:
package com.keybox.manage.action;

import com.keybox.common.util.AppConfig;
import com.keybox.common.util.AuthUtil;
import com.keybox.manage.db.AuthDB;
import com.keybox.manage.model.Auth;
import com.keybox.manage.model.User;
import com.keybox.manage.util.OTPUtil;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.*;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


/**
 * Action to auth to keybox
 */
@Namespace("/")
@ParentPackage("struts-default")
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final Logger loginAuditLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.keybox.manage.action.LoginAudit");
    private HttpServletResponse servletResponse;
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    private Auth auth;
    private static final String AUTH_ERROR = "Authentication Failed: Login credentials are invalid";
    private static final String AUTH_ERROR_NO_PROFILE = "Authentication Failed: There are no profiles assigned to this account";
    private boolean otpEnabled = "required".equals(AppConfig.getProperty("oneTimePassword")) || "optional".equals(AppConfig.getProperty("oneTimePassword"));
    private String _csrf;

    @Action(value = "login", results = {
            @Result(name = "success", location = "/login.jsp")
    })
    public String login() {
        HttpSession session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            session = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(true);
        }
        _csrf = AuthUtil.generateCSRFToken(session);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "admin/menu", results = {
            @Result(name = "success", location = "/admin/menu.jsp")
    })
    public String menu() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Action(value = "loginSubmit", results = {
            @Result(name = "input", location = "/login.jsp"),
            @Result(name = "change_password", location = "/admin/userSettings.action", type = "redirect"),
            @Result(name = "otp", location = "/admin/viewOTP.action", type = "redirect"),
            @Result(name = "success", location = "/admin/menu.action", type = "redirect")
    })
    public String loginSubmit() {
        String retVal = SUCCESS;
        String authToken = AuthDB.login(auth);
        String clientIP = AuthUtil.getClientIPAddress(servletRequest);

        if (authToken != null) {
            User user = AuthDB.getUserByAuthToken(authToken);
            if (user != null) {
                String sharedSecret = null;
                if (otpEnabled) {
                    sharedSecret = AuthDB.getSharedSecret(user.getId());
                    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sharedSecret) && (auth.getOtpToken() == null || !OTPUtil.verifyToken(sharedSecret, auth.getOtpToken()))) {
                        loginAuditLogger.info(auth.getUsername() + " (" + clientIP + ") - " + AUTH_ERROR);
                        addActionError(AUTH_ERROR);
                        return INPUT;
                    }
                }
                if (!User.MANAGER.equals(user.getUserType()) && (user.getProfileList() == null || user.getProfileList().size() <= 0)) {
                    loginAuditLogger.info(auth.getUsername() + " (" + clientIP + ") - " + AUTH_ERROR_NO_PROFILE);
                    addActionError(AUTH_ERROR_NO_PROFILE);
                    return INPUT;
                }

                AuthUtil.setAuthToken(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(), authToken);
                AuthUtil.setUserId(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(), user.getId());
                AuthUtil.setAuthType(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(), user.getAuthType());
                AuthUtil.setTimeout(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession());
                AuthUtil.setUsername(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(), user.getUsername());

                if (otpEnabled && StringUtils.isEmpty(sharedSecret)) {
                    retVal = "otp";
                } else if ("changeme".equals(auth.getPassword()) && Auth.AUTH_BASIC.equals(user.getAuthType())) {
                    retVal = "change_password";
                }
                loginAuditLogger.info(auth.getUsername() + " (" + clientIP + ") - Authentication Success");
            }
        } else {
            loginAuditLogger.info(auth.getUsername() + " (" + clientIP + ") - " + AUTH_ERROR);
            addActionError(AUTH_ERROR);
            retVal = INPUT;
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    @Action(value = "logout", results = {
            @Result(name = "success", location = "/login.action", type = "redirect")
    })
    public String logout() {
        AuthUtil.deleteAllSession(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(true));
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public void validateLoginSubmit() {
        if (auth.getUsername() == null || auth.getUsername().trim().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("auth.username", "Required");
        }
        if (auth.getPassword() == null || auth.getPassword().trim().isEmpty()) {
            addFieldError("auth.password", "Required");
        }
    }

    // Getters and setters for auth, servletRequest, servletResponse, and _csrf
    public Auth getAuth() {
        return auth;
    }

    public void setAuth(Auth auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    public HttpServletResponse getServletResponse() {
        return servletResponse;
    }

    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
        this.servletResponse = servletResponse;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest() {
        return servletRequest;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        this.servletRequest = servletRequest;
    }

    public String get_csrf() {
        return _csrf;
    }

    public void set_csrf(String _csrf) {
        this._csrf = _csrf;
    }
}

And here are my struts.xml and web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 6.0//EN"
        "https://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-6.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="redirect" class="com.keybox.common.result.CSRFRedirectionResult"/>
        </result-types>
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="CSRFToken" class="com.keybox.common.interceptor.CSRFInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="HSTS" class="com.keybox.common.interceptor.HTTPStrictTransportSecurityInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="Clickjacking" class="com.keybox.common.interceptor.ClickjackingInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="keyboxStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="CSRFToken">
                    <param name="excludeMethods">login,logout</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="HSTS"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="Clickjacking"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <global-results>
            <result name="invalid.token">/</result>
        </global-results>

        <action name="login" class="com.keybox.manage.action.LoginAction" method="login">
            <result name="success">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    

    </package>

    <package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="menu" class="com.keybox.manage.action.LoginAction" method="menu">
            <result name="success">/admin/menu.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>



    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/>
</struts>

web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.keybox.common.filter.AuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/manage/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.action</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>

